# How to animate the gltf model with threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a cube model which is GLTF format, now i am trying to animate it by changing the textures material.

Now currently, there are 300 heat map images as the texture material, the requirement from supervisor is animating the cube model by loading heat map images one by one. 
[Texture materials set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCh14.png)

About the animation, I tried to use VectorKeyFrameTrack to change the child.material. But it does not work. 
the codes:

```
    if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false) {
    document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
}
var camera, scene, renderer;
init();

function init() {
    //init scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x999999);

    //add directional light and spotlight
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(3, 15.0, -29).normalize();

    scene.add(light);

    var light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(-20, 7.0, -2).normalize();
    scene.add(light1);
    var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(-5, 15.0, 30).normalize();
    scene.add(light2);
    var light3 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(15, 5.0, -15).normalize();
    scene.add(light3);


    //add camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
    camera.position.y = 5;
    camera.position.z = 10;
    scene.add(camera);

    //add grid
    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 50, 0xffffff, 0x555555);
    scene.add(grid);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    //Generate textures array
    var loadedTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("1.png");
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loadedTexture});

    var loadedTexture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("2.png");
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loadedTexture2});

    //Load Collada file

    var path = "./image/"
    var format = ".png";
    var a = "Avg_Displacement_";
    var material_list = [];
    var times = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 314; i++) {


        var loadedTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(path + a + i + format);

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loadedTexture});

        material_list.push(material);
        times.push(i);

    }


    console.log(material_list);
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('scene.gltf', function (gltf) {

        gltf.scene.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
        // console.log(gltf.scene.children[0].material);
        // var kf = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack( '.scene.material', times, material_list );
        // var clip = new THREE.AnimationClip('Action', 315, [kf]);
        //
        // mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf);

        // var clipAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
        // clipAction.play();

        gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child.isMesh) {

                var kf = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack('child.material', times, material_list);
                var clip = new THREE.AnimationClip('Action', 3, [kf]);

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(child);

                var clipAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                clipAction.play()

                // child.material = material;

            }

            scene.add(gltf.scene);
        });
    });


    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change', render);
    controls.update();
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// function animate() {
//
//     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
//
//     mesh.material.map.offset.x += 0.005;
//     mesh.material.map.offset.y += 0.005;
//
//     renderer.render( scene, camera );
//
// }
```

[child.material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IlDW.png)

the second problem is how to animate the model by loading each image as the texture as material.

Comment: Can you please share the `glTF` file in this thread? One way to animate the texture is to animate `Texture.offset` like in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/15056/. `Texture.offset` influences the transformation of uv-coordinates in the shader.

Comment: @Mugen87 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpSMCXRDx-I_FMbAgQr_3OaA2GrSQP3v/view?usp=sharing  this is the GlTF model I use in project.  I need to animate the model by load the heat map image one by one. the heat map images is attached

Comment: @LiyingShi Just use `MeshBasicMaterial`. Omit the shadows and lights. Create a single texture from your heat maps, and animate `material.map.offset`.

Comment: Thanks for all those advises, it works perfect@WestLangley. just only a small essue, there are 315 heat maps, and it really is a huge single texture now